# Excel Formulas to calculate time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, time

I have a call tracking system which tells me number of dials & talk time. The talk time is in HH:MM:SS format.
So I am trying to create a formula to ADD all of the call times together but every formula I've tried gives me quirky results because it converts incorrectly.
An example: (0:26) - should be 26 seconds. Whenever I try to create a formula it converts that to 26 minutes.
Here is a copy of what I am trying to TOTAL, can someone please help give me a formula that I can use to calculate HH:MM:SS so I can total all of our calls for the day.

Appreciate any help in advance on this - got me stumped!

Example of the data:

```
NO ANSWER   0:26    
ANSWERED    1:43    
ANSWERED    2:39    
ANSWERED    0:41    
ANSWERED    0:26    
ANSWERED    0:19    
ANSWERED    0:21    
ANSWERED    0:45    
ANSWERED    5:42    
ANSWERED    0:41    
ANSWERED    0:25
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is not a service site, so we aren't just going to do it for you. Please share with us how you have the columns formatted and what formula you are currently using. We will try to help resolve the "quirky results".

Comment: I've tried using:
 [ =sum(J2:J11) ] & the formatting is CUSTOM / h:mm:ss

When doing that it doesn't give correct time as results - it converts the "Seconds" to minutes & doesn't calculate correctly - for example: If you look at what I pasted above with times, when I use formula it gives me (11:08) - which is incorrect because there is more than (11:08) minutes worth of call & time elapsed.

Comment: Duration 1 of 2 in data.
0:26
1:43
2:39
0:41
0:26
0:19
0:21
0:45
5:42
0:41
0:25
0:27
0:11
0:21
0:35
0:23
0:22
0:25
0:13
0:30
0:20
0:23
0:07
0:06
0:22
0:25
0:15
0:29
0:13
0:27
0:39
0:24
0:37
0:47
0:16
0:35
0:16
0:39
0:39
0:49
0:10
1:30
0:38
2:47
1:23
0:40
1:05
0:52
0:35
0:33
0:19
0:34

Comment: 2 of 2 in Data:0:14
0:40
0:07
0:38
0:40
0:29
0:45
0:45
0:29
0:41
0:35
0:11
0:30
0:37
0:36
0:11
0:37
0:51
0:20
0:40
0:17
0:42
0:15
0:34
0:22
0:53
1:17
2:55
0:07
0:46
0:34
0:41
0:39
0:41
0:36
1:06
0:43
0:16
0:40
0:14
1:33
1:03
1:19
1:25
7:46
0:56
0:26
0:26
0:35
1:01
0:48
0:36
0:31
0:13
0:23
0:23
0:37
0:44

Comment: Are you entering in the times manually? or are they populated from another source?

Comment: chcuk's comment is very relevant because it sort of drives the solution.  Times are stores as a number (decimal fraction of a day), and you can do regular math on the values.  If you format the cell as time, Excel will give you options for how to format and display it.  If you enter values in the form nn:nn, Excel will interpret that as hours and minutes, and convert that to an equivalent decimal value for storage.  So there are a number of ways to get to the solution you want, but the choices depend on what Excel thinks is there.

Comment: chcuk - they are populated from another source, I am copy & pasting into excel to attempt to use excel to give me totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel only knows what we tell it.

This has to do with formatting more than anything. You are using `h:mm:ss`, but only given `0:00`. This results in Excel thinking you want hours and minutes.

If you enter the times as `0:00:26` it will know what was originally `0:26` is 26 seconds and calculate correctly.

To convert your current values, divide them by 60.

[image]

You can then calculate the sum of the column accordingly to get the proper total `h:mm:ss`.

Comment: This solution WORKED - THANK YOU!!
could not for the life of me figure out on my own, Really Appreciate the assistance to everyone who took time to reply!

Comment: Glad to help. To show your question has an answer that solved your problem, please check accept under the voting buttons to the left.

Comment: Think I did that correctly, again.... Thank you for your assistance CharlieRB

Answer (score 0):

You may have to subtract your time from 24 h to arrive at common sense value. Excel doesn't appear to add time correctly as you have deduced. Subtracting time seems to work just fine, though.

Comment: My apologies if I sound retarded, but I don't know how to do that. I guess this is the wrong site to ask for help on, but figured someone here might be able to get me steered in the right direction since this has literally occupied over 4 hours of internet searches & trial & error only to not get an actual resolve. Very frustrating because I do ok with most other formula calculations when using Excel - this just has me stuck.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMIF(A1:A20,"answered",B1:B20)/60`
Where
Sumif to Sum only the Answered only
 A1:A20 is the column of Answered, No Answer
B1:B20 is the column of Time
and 60 to convert to minute instead of hours to have the right format

Comment: Read the question carefully. The OP does not ask how to only sum the `Answered` lines. They are asking how to calculate the times correctly.

Comment: @CharlieRB **Excel Formulas to calculate time** this is the title and **can someone please help give me a formula that I can use to calculate HH:MM:SS so I can total all of our calls for the day.**

Comment: I converted the result to have a real value you can do the same for all the column of time

Comment: Not sure if you are both the same "Sam", but we should not answer based on the title alone. Reading the title AND the question tells us what the OP is dealing with and what they need help with. That is if they have explained it well. The point of my comment was to offer advice for future answers to be more accurate.